# Static predefined constant objects in a class

Tags: c#, static

I am working on a C# game that will have predefined levels. I am trying to have a class that will hold the predefined data of all of the levels. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
public static GameLevel startLevel = new Level() {
   startLevel.Actions.Add(action);
   startLevel.Actions.Add(action);
}
```

And so on. However, it seems that C# does not want me to initialize this way. How can I achieve my desired effect without throwing it into a massive constructor?

Answer (score 0):

How do you think if we change the static variable as below:

```
private static GameLevel _startLevel;
public static GameLevel StartLevel
{
    get
    {
        if(_startLevel == null)
        {
            _startLevel = new Level();
            _startLevel.Action.Add(action1);
            _startLevel.Action.Add(action2);
        }

        return _startLevel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*"...C# does not want me to initialize this way..."*

You can init this way. You simply don't have the right syntax. This should work

```
public static Level startLevel = new Level() 
    {
        Actions = new List<Action>() 
            {
                new Action() {...},
                new Action() {...}    
            },
        OtherProprty = "Other"
    };
```

NOTE: this has to be done under class scope

*"Massive constructor"* - you usually don't init static members in constructor unless this is static constructor. Sounds like you need to use **Singleton** pattern for this piece. Then again, you call all the needed code in constructor, "massive" or not. Break it into methods.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have predefined levels, I suggest a little different approach.

Create a Level base class, and a class for each Level. The constructor for each level class can set up the Actions and any other things the game needs to know how to display itself.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new GameState(new Level1());
        Console.WriteLine("Current level is " + GameState.CurrentLevel.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("User leveled up");
        GameState.CurrentLevel = new Level2();
        Console.WriteLine("Current level is " + GameState.CurrentLevel.Name);
    }
}

public class Level
{   
    public string Name;
    // public static IEnumerable<Action> Actions { get; set; }
}

public class Level1 : Level
{
    public Level1()
    {
        // level 1 init
        Name = "1";
        // Actions = new List<Action> { ... }
    }
}

public class Level2 : Level
{
    public Level2()
    {
        // level 2 init
        Name = "2";
    }
}

public class GameState
{
    public static Level CurrentLevel { get; set; }

    public GameState(Level startLevel)
    {
        CurrentLevel = startLevel;
    }
}
```

Working copy: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qMxUbw